# Nordic SDK where to receive data?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have started working with Nordic android SDK. And I have managed to make my sensors-devices subscribe and publish to group I have them assigned to. Problem is that my messages that I should receive in meshMessages doesn't contain  enough data. From my device-sensor I have data sent in packed like code bellow.

```
{
    uint32_t srcMac4;
    uint8_t remoteTypeID;
    uint8_t opCode;
    uint8_t statusData[16];
} generic_onoff_status_msg_pkt_t;
```

I can read data in my meshMessages when I cast them to GenericOnOfStatus. Problem is that I'm receiving only 6 bytes and I should see more like 12 in one message.

How can I make my app receive more byte data in GenericOnOfStatus messages?

I have used Nordic app as guideline for me how to implement code so far. https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-nRF-Mesh-Library

Comment: For nordic specific help you can also ask directly at https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/

Comment: I have tried couple of times to create account on their support forum but for some reason I'm not getting any response from them. Documentation doesn't help to.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution. Problem is with Nordic SDK. They have problem's with their library at the moment. When we try to set unicast address in filter (White or Black listing) somehow it doesn't recognize it as unicast address and that makes app crash. Workaround at this moment until they have it patched is to switch to dev branch of library.